# Why does Gaussian wave packet spread out in potential well but not in harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Gaussian wave packet spread out in potential well. But it oscillate in harmonic oscillator. Can you explain it qualitatively?

Comment: The infinite square well vaguely *looks* like the harmonic well, but its hamiltonian does not transform to basically itself under Fourier transformation, in sharp contrast to the harmonic H. If you have the square well in mind, it is closer to the free system, once you unfold it at the boundaries. Comparing the free phase-space propagator to the harmonic one you see the phase-space shear in the free one, unlike the rigid motion of the harmonic one: a quick sweetener on the superiority of the [phase space formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation) for some purposes...